# Way to see if a Google Maps place is verified/claimed without access to someones GMB account

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api, google-my-business-api

Is there a way to see if a Google Maps place is verified/claimed on GMB? At the moment we use the place details API to get the details for a specific location. However the place details API does not provide us with a way to see if the location has been verified/claimed.

The problem is that we don't have access to the GMB account for the found location so we can't check if the "place_id" in the GMB response is equal to the one we use for getting the place details.

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately, the verified/claimed property of the business place is not exposed in the Places API at the moment. I can see a feature request in the Google issue tracker to add verified/claimed field in the response of place details:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35819976

Currently this feature request has 60 stars, however it looks like Google didn't set high priority on this task. Feel free to star the feature request to express your interest and subscribe to further notifications.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I will add a star to the issue. Hopefully Google will pick it up.